# Como hacer para que mi programa no inserte campos vacios a mi bd? Python3 SQLite

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python3. Para ser mas especifico estoy trabajando con Tkinter y SQLite.
Tengo una tabla llamada **Comentarios** con 4 campos(**Nombre,mail,direccion y comentarios**, los cuales tengo declarados como NOT NULL en dicha tabla) y un form con los mismos campos para llenarlos y mandarlos a la BD despues de presionar un boton que tengo programado.

Mi problema es que al correr el form, estoy probando que funcione eso del NOT NULL. Lleno el campo de Nombre y los demas los dejo vacios y al presionar el boton de enviar datos, estos si se mandan a la BD. Cosa que no debería suceder porque como dije antes, estos campos son NOT NULL.

Les dejo el codigo que tiene el boton:

```
def enviarDatos():

#Obtener datos
nombre=enNombre.get()
mail=enMail.get()
direccion=enDireccion.get()
comentarios=txtComentarios.get("1.0","end") 
comentarios=comentarios.strip()
print (nombre.strip(), mail.strip(),direccion.strip(),comentarios.strip()) #Este print lo hice porque creí que tal vez python me estaba enviando un espacio en blanco en esos campos vacios, y despues comprobé con un print(len()) para cada campo y estos me marcaban 0 y aun asi pasa los datos en blanco a la BD.

#insertar datos en la bd 
try:
        crud.insert(nombre,mail,direccion,comentarios)

except Exception as e:
    messagebox.showerror("Error","Error al insertar datos",str(e))
finally:
    pass
```

Como pueden ver, programe un Try catch, el cual me debería lanzar un Messagebox con un error porque debe de detectar que estoy enviando campos vacios, pero por alguna razon, estos datos a pesar de estar vacíos, igual se pasan a la BD.

Les dejo el codigo del CRUD.Insert que tengo escrito en el Try:

```
def insert(self,nombre,mail,direccion,comentarios):
    entry=(nombre,mail,direccion,comentarios)
    insertTable="Insert into comentarios values(NULL,?,?,?,?)"
    print (len(nombre), len(mail),len(direccion),len(comentarios))
    cursor.execute(insertTable,entry)
    con.commit()
```

[image: Este es un ejemplo de la tabla Comentarios:]

Alguna idea de que está sucediendo aqui?
De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que queda guardado en la bbdd? ejecuta un `select * from comentarios` y muestranos el resultado. Me da que lo que sucede es que no te envia null, sino una cadena vacia (y eso es distinto de null). Tambien, si puedes, publica el schema de esa tabla

Comment: Ya anexé una imagen amigo

Comment: ok. prueba esta otra consulta: `select * from comentarios where comentario is null;` a ver si te devuelve elementos. Si no te devuelve esos 6 elementos entonces te esta escribiendo cadenas vacias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una cosa es enviar `Null` y otra cosa es enviar una cadena vacía, que es lo que tu envías. En Python es la diferencia entre `None` y `""`.

Ten en cuenta que `tkinter.Entry.get`/`tkinter.StringVar.get` retorna una cadena vacía si el Entry/StringVar están vacíos, no `None`.

El intento de inserción en un campo `NOT NUL` generará un `IntegrityError` solo si se intenta insertar un valor nulo, lo que en Python es `None`, una cadena vacía es equivalente a insertar `0` en un campo `INTEGER`. Si quieres validar de ésta forma la entrada necesitas enviar `None` en la query cuando `get` retorne una cadena vacía.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3


db = sqlite3.connect("file::memory")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (nombre TEXT NOT NULL)")
db.commit()


def enviar():
    nombre = entry_nombre.get() or None # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    with db:
        try:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO test(nombre) VALUES(?)", (nombre, ))
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error al insertar datos", str(e))


root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="Nombre").pack()
entry_nombre = tk.Entry(root)
entry_nombre.pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Enviar", command=enviar).pack()
root.mainloop()
db.close()
```

Eso si, es mucho más simple y eficiente hacer ésto en Python:

```
def enviar():
    if nombre:= entry_nombre.get(): 
        with db:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO test(nombre) VALUES(?)", (nombre, ))
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(
            "Error al insertar datos",
            "El campo <nombre> es obligatorio"
             )
```

---

La expresión:

```
variable = expresion or None
```

lo que hace primero es evaluar `expresion` como en cualquier `or`:

- Si es verdadera (`bool(expresion)`), la variable queda asociada al valor resutado de evaluar la expresión.
- Si es evaluada como falsa se asigna `None` a la variable.

> ```
> >>> var = 5 or None
> >>> var
> 5
>
> >>> var = 0 or None
> >>> var
> None
>
> >>> var = "hola" or None
> >>> var
> 'Hola'
>
> >>> var = "" or None
> >>> var
> None
>
> >>> var = [1, 2] or None
> >>> var
> [1, 2]
>
> >>> var = [] or None
> >>> var
> None
>
> >>> var = 3**2-9 or None
> >>> var
> None
>
> >>> var = 3**2 + 7 or None
> >>> var
> 16
> ```

Tener en cuanta que todo contenedor vacío en Python se evalúa como `False`, así como `int(0)`, `float(0)`, ..., `None` y obviamente `False`.

Comment: Muchas gracias! La solucion estaba en escribir "nombre=entry_nombre or None". Desconocía que se podía hacer esto..entieno que es como declarar una variable de cierta forma segun sea el caso...te agradecería si me pudieras orientar donde puedo conslutar mas acerca de este tipo de declaraciones. 

Por lo mientras gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Hola Diego, he editado la respuesta, mira al final a ver si te aclara algo. Si sigues con dudas no te cortes en comentar. Saludos.

Comment: Súper bien explicado amigo...muchas gracias! Un saludo desde Mexico!